# Use the terminal's autocomplete path feature for input to a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, terminal

I want to make a script that: (1) Gets a path giving the user the ability to use tab to autocomplete, then (2) gets a filename from the user, and then (3) creates a file at that path with extension .txt.

**My question is:** How do I do 1.? How do I tell bash to ask for input that is an "autocompletable" path, preferably with part of the path (say ~/x/) already filled out by default?

Note: the paths will almost always include spaces.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
read -p "enter a directory: " -i "$HOME/x/" -e path
```

From a bash session, enter `help read|less`

Comment: Thanks! On osx I get this error: "-bash: read: -i: invalid option
read: usage: read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]" Is this an osx thing?

Comment: It does work in Debian, which is where I plan to use it. :)

Comment: you probably have an older version of bash on your mac: `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: The `-i` flag was added in `bash` 4.0. `help '[r]ead'` to get the help for `read` only. Note that while `read -e` will be able to complete inside `~`, it will not be expanded.

Comment: Thanks Stephane. What does that mean? (Probably (certainly) a stupid question.)

Comment: It means you'll get the literal tilde in the $path variable, which may be difficult to handle. In hindsight, use `-i "$HOME/x/"`

Comment: If you want to have `bash` 4.x on OS X, it's only as far away as [`homebrew`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)  :)